# If $\sin x=\frac{2 t}{1+t^{2}}$ and $\cot y=\frac{1-t^{2}}{2 t}$, then the value of $\frac{d^{2} x}{d y^{2}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> If $\sin x=\frac{2 t}{1+t^{2}}$ and $\cot y=\frac{1-t^{2}}{2 t}$, then the value of $\frac{d^{2} x}{d y^{2}}$

If we take $t=\tan \theta$ then $x=2\theta$ and for $y$  ,I am getting two values as follows ,

if we apply identity $\tan 2 A=\frac{2 \tan A}{1-\tan ^{2} A}$ then we get $y=2\theta$

and if we take $\tan \theta $ common from $\dfrac{1-\tan^2 \theta}{2\tan\theta}$  and simplify then we get $y= \dfrac{\pi}{4} + \theta$ ?

how we are getting two values of $y$ ?

thankyou

Comment: could you be clear about "and if I take..."?

Comment: @Arnaldo got my mistake,we will not get $y= \dfrac{\pi}{4} + \theta$,sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're getting $y=\theta+\pi/4$ but it is definitely incorrect as $$\cot(\theta+\pi/4)=\frac{1-\tan\theta\tan\pi/4}{\tan\theta+\tan\pi/4}=\frac{1-\tan\theta}{1+\tan\theta}$$ is not the same as $$\frac{1-t^2}{2t}=\frac{1-\tan^2\theta}{2\tan\theta}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The Complete solution to this problem is to be found here

> Substitute t by tan x, then use double angle formulae. Full solution [HERE](https://www.sarthaks.com/536891/if-sin-x-2t-1-t-2-and-cot-y-1-t-2-2t-find-the-value-of-d-2y-dx-2-3) or [HERE](https://brainly.in/question/9341140)

As per your doubt of getting two answers is concerned, it definitely has some error, and it would be better if you elaborate. But I suppose you have done some error in evaluating the inverse functions with their stringent rules......

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1541722)

Comment: ohk i didnt knew that. i thought it would be taking credit for other's work.......

Comment: As far as credit goes, you can still provide the link

Comment: Added the essential approach, also added an alternative link